# How do I find out what the terminator of a line from a CSV file

Tags: csv, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use the Bulk insert in sqlserver 2012 to import data from a CSV .

My csv file comes from a third party.

I need to find out what the Row File Terminator .

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Text Editor to find the right encoding and deduce the row line and row file terminator.

Usualy it is something like : %x1A