# BULK INSERT fails - tried many variations on row delimiter

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk

I am struggling to script a `BULK INSERT` for my `.dat` files. I am getting many errors depending on what I try, but I'm pretty sure it's related to the row delimiter. I can successfully use the SQL import wizard for my `.dat` files. Under "Specify the characters that delimit the source file", I see the following as defaults that I accept:

```
Row delimiter: {CR}{LF}   
Column delimiter: Comma {,}
```

The 500k rows and 158 columns come in just beautifully thanks to the wizard.

When scripting, I have tried all manner of `\r\n` variations and `0x0a` etc and searched for help and reviewed similar posts. I can successfully script in a single line of real data, so I don’t think the column parsing is an issue. It fails when I try 2 lines in a dummy file. The least amount of errors I generate occurs with the following

```
bulk insert abc
from 'C:\TestDat\try2.dat'
with (FIRSTROW = 1, fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\r\n')
go
```

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 158 (Column 157).

(using 0x0a will create more errors on a 2 line file).

.dat contents:

```
xxx,20080501,xxx,xxx:175000,55008654,0178636,202307011001,001859915,OK,W,xx,1.0,00000100,48,202306290100,R0,2,202306290200,R0,0,202306290300,R0,0,202306290400,R0,0,202306290500,R0,1,202306290600,R0,1,202306290700,R0,0,202306290800,R0,0,202306290900,R0,0,202306291000,R0,0,202306291100,R0,0,202306291200,R0,1,202306291300,R0,0,202306291400,R0,0,202306291500,R0,2,202306291600,R0,1,202306291700,R0,0,202306291800,R0,0,202306291900,R0,0,202306292000,R0,0,202306292100,R0,0,202306292200,R0,0,202306292300,R0,2,202306300000,R0,3,202306300100,R0,0,202306300200,R0,0,202306300300,R0,2,202306300400,R0,0,202306300500,R0,1,202306300600,R0,1,202306300700,R0,3,202306300800,R0,0,202306300900,R0,0,202306301000,R0,0,202306301100,R0,0,202306301200,R0,3,202306301300,R0,1,202306301400,R0,0,202306301500,R0,1,202306301600,R0,1,202306301700,R0,0,202306301800,R0,0,202306301900,R0,1,202306302000,R0,0,202306302100,R0,1,202306302200,R0,0,202306302300,R0,1,202307010000,R0,0
xxx,20080501,xxx,xxx:175000,55008654,0178636,202307011001,001859915,OK,W,xx,1.0,00000100,4,202307010100,R0,1,202307010200,R0,0,202307010300,R0,1,202307010400,R0,0
```

Comment: "It fails when I try 2 lines in a dummy file"   Please add the contents of this dummy file, so we have a [mre], and the DDL for table `abc`

Comment: I'm new here - what is the best way to add my data, or file?

Comment: `BULK INSERT` normally reads file which are just TEXT, so you can add it to your post (between triple back quotes)?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have the same number of columns in each row.

Comment: Thanks very much - will investigate your suggestions. I agree that each row does not have the same amount of columns - that it just the way it is, but I am confident 158 is the max and is correct for the first row of data.

Comment: May you an use my tip, see end of my answer. It was also a suggestion done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604929/724039

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link above.  This seems to confirm that BULK INSERT is never going to work with an inconsistent number of columns between rows.   I did explore the workaround but I'm not sure I understand the end game here. When testing on try2.dat it produced a single column with 183 rows.  On Row 158 it showed 0 xxx, which is where the true line ends (where 158 should = 0 and 159 = xxx).  At this point I am just leaning towards manual upload via the wizard, for this project, can you explain the work around a little more?

Comment: One more piece of information that we might be able to leverage is that each row contains information about how many columns there will be. The column count per row will equal 14+n*3 where n = the value in the 14th column.

Comment: I added, a _last_ attempt , to my answer. 

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm going to mark yours as the answer here as I have certainly learned a couple of things.  Although I don't have control of the input files, I think the easiest way for me to handle this problem overall is to convert the .dat to .txt tab delimited (with a VBA script).  I was testing this out and it seems to then allow BULK INSERT to work as each row brings in a bunch of NULLs to complete out 158 columns per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I created the `try2.dat` file,

and i created a table `abc` using (I left out column3..column157, but they have same definition....);

```
CREATE TABLE abc 
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(200),
    Column2 VARCHAR(200),
    ...
    Column158 VARCHAR(200),
    Column159 VARCHAR(200)
)
```

Then started SQLCMD

```
D:\TEMP>sqlcmd
1> use test
2> go
Changed database context to 'TEST'.
1> delete from abc;
2>
3> go

(1 rows affected)
1>
2> bulk insert abc from 'd:\temp\try2.dat' with (FIRSTROW = 1, fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\r\n')
3> go

(1 rows affected)
```

When you are getting an error, I see two possibilities:

- I you have one column less than me (I do have 159 columns)
- The line separator is not the same, see: [How do I find out what the terminator of a line from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972152/how-do-i-find-out-what-the-terminator-of-a-line-from-a-csv-file).

When selecting the table in SSMS, I do see:

[![start of the row][1]][1]

[![end of the row][2]][2]

The last column does not seem to be OK...... More investigation needed....

A **workaround** could be:

Create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE def
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

and import using (since you do not have `#` characters in your file):

```
bulk insert def from 'd:\temp\try2.dat' 
with (FIRSTROW = 1, fieldterminator = '#', rowterminator = '\r\n')
```

After that, you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT Column1 FROM def), ',');
```

Resulting in:

| value |
| --- |
| xxx |
| 20080501 |
| xxx |
| xxx:175000 |
| 55008654 |
| 0178636 |
| 202307011001 |
| 001859915 |
| OK |
| W |
| xx |
| 1.0 |
| 00000100 |
| 48 |
| 202306290100 |
| R0 |
| ........ |

NOTE: When your version of SQL is new enough, you can add the `enable_ordinal`  parameter to [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

NOTE2: Why is this `enable_ordinal` added to STRING_SPLIT?

Because in the old (or current ) way it works, STRING SPLIT does not "care" about ordinal position (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64092709/724039)

I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/YzXLnigq) with your data, this has a line number added to `def`

Part of the `SELECT R, value FROM def d CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT((SELECT Column1 ), ',');` (near the line change) is:

| R | value |
| --- | --- |
|  | ... |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 202307010400 |
| 1 | R0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | xxx |
| 2 | 20080501 |
| 2 | xxx |
| 2 | xxx:175000 |
|  | ... |

Unfortunately it is not possible (AFAIK) to add row number per line number in a ***reliable*** way...

**ANOTHER ATTEMPT**:

seeing: "The column count per row will equal 14+n*3 where n = the value in the 14th column."

Define your import table (here named with the clumsy name `def2`:

```
CREATE TABLE def2 (
  Column1 VARCHAR(200),
  Column2 VARCHAR(200),
  Column3 VARCHAR(200),
  Column4 VARCHAR(200),
  Column5 VARCHAR(200),
  Column6 VARCHAR(200),
  Column7 VARCHAR(200),
  Column8 VARCHAR(200),
  Column9 VARCHAR(200),
  Column10 VARCHAR(200),
  Column11 VARCHAR(200),
  Column12 VARCHAR(200),
  Column13 VARCHAR(200),
  Column14 VARCHAR(200),
  ColumnRest VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

Import your data:

```
bulk insert def2 from 'D:\Temp\try2.dat' with (fieldterminator = ',');
```

Finally get the values, which can be used to be inserted in a (new) table:

```
WITH def2tmp AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnRest) as R, Column14, RTRIM(ColumnRest) + ',' as ColumnRest
   FROM def2
), PosComma AS (
   SELECT 
       R , 
       Column14, 
       CHARINDEX(',',ColumnRest,1) as R2, 
       SUBSTRING(ColumnRest,1,CHARINDEX(',',ColumnRest,1)-1) as value
       ,ColumnRest
   FROM def2tmp
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
       R, 
       Column14, 
       CHARINDEX(',',ColumnRest,R2+1), 
       SUBSTRING(ColumnRest,R2+1,CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(',',ColumnRest,R2+1)-R2)-1 < 0 THEN 100 ELSE (CHARINDEX(',',ColumnRest,R2+1)-R2)-1 END)
       ,ColumnRest
   FROM PosComma
   WHERE R2<LEN(ColumnRest) and r<=2
)
SELECt 
   R, 
   R2, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R ORDER BY R2) as R3,
   value as value 
FROM PosComma
ORDER BY column14 DESC,R2 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20000)
;
```

output (where `R` is the row number from your import table, and `R3` is the row number of the values (`R2` is the position of the `,` in `ColumnRest`)):

P.S. SORRY for this messy output....

This solution gets you two tables, the first `def2` with the first 14 columns, the second with the values in that row (but you have to define that table yourself!)

| R | R2 | R3 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 1 | 202306290100 |
| 1 | 16 | 2 | R0 |
| 1 | 18 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 31 | 4 | 202306290200 |
| 1 | 34 | 5 | R0 |
| 1 | 36 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | 49 | 7 | 202306290300 |
| 1 | 52 | 8 | R0 |
| 1 | 54 | 9 | 0 |
| 1 | 67 | 10 | 202306290400 |
| 1 | 70 | 11 | R0 |
| 1 | 72 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | 85 | 13 | 202306290500 |
| 1 | ... | ... | ...... |
| 1 | 823 | 136 | 202306302200 |
| 1 | 826 | 137 | R0 |
| 1 | 828 | 138 | 0 |
| 1 | 841 | 139 | 202306302300 |
| 1 | 844 | 140 | R0 |
| 1 | 846 | 141 | 1 |
| 1 | 859 | 142 | 202307010000 |
| 1 | 862 | 143 | R0 |
| 1 | 864 | 144 | 0 |
| 2 | 13 | 1 | 202307010100 |
| 2 | 16 | 2 | R0 |
| 2 | 18 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 31 | 4 | 202307010200 |
| 2 | 34 | 5 | R0 |
| 2 | 36 | 6 | 0 |
| 2 | 49 | 7 | 202307010300 |
| 2 | 52 | 8 | R0 |
| 2 | 54 | 9 | 1 |
| 2 | 67 | 10 | 202307010400 |
| 2 | 70 | 11 | R0 |
| 2 | 72 | 12 | 0 |